Cost of GetBucketMetadata request
I would like to know how much we pay for GetBucketMetadata api request. But I didn't found which class operation is it. Any idea?
I checked the class operations documentation and documentation for GetBucketMetadata request.

Under the hood this operation is originally storage.buckets.get api call which one is operation class B according this documentation. So the cost is around $0.0004 per 1000 operations.
